# No host_name when connecting to SQL Server from ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am facing problems deploying an ASP.NET Core Web API using Entity Framework Core.

When I connect to the SQL Server, the session has no host_name, in development there's no problem and works fine, but the production servers have a Logon Trigger that checks the host_name and the login_name, so I'm getting the error Logon failed for login 'user' due to trigger execution.

When I compare the sessions from a ASP.NET Web API using Entity Framework and the ASP.NET Core, the Core version has no host_name:

```
SELECT *
FROM SYS.DM_EXEC_SESSIONS
where login_name like '%user%'`
```

[image: Session ASP.NET Core vs ASP.NET Web API]

Is there a way for ASP.NET Core to send the host_name in the connection to SQL Server?

I'm using AspNetCore v1.0.1 and EntityFrameworkCore v1.1.0

Comment: How do you get the host name ? I mean C# code, maybe in production there isn't some configuration that doesn't return the host name, in that case you can try with ip address

Comment: I'm not getting the host name, I connect with EF CORE, it should automatically add the host name to the connection, like Entity Framework in ASP.NET